# c# new object(data) always creates empty objects

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to c# and I'm trying to create a custom object, but they always seem to be empty.

```
public class Item
{
    public string itemName {get;set;}
    public int itemAmount {get;set;}
    public Item (string name, int amount)
    {
        name = itemName;
        amount = itemAmount;
    }
}

public class Backpack : MonoBehaviour
{    
    void Start()
    {
       Item gold = new Item ("gold", 5)
    }
}
```

When I try to get gold parameters I get `null, 0`. Should it work like that? I wanted to use it to quickly add items to a list, and right now I would have to change all of them manually with something like
 `gold.itemName = "gold"; gold.itemAmount = 5`.
Can I do it in another way?

Comment: Typo: itemName = name; itemAmount = amount;  Make it more intuitive by writing this.itemName = name;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assignment in the constructor is the wrong way around, instead it should be:

```
public Item (string name, int amount)
{
    itemName = name;
    itemAmount = amount;
}
```